# Firebase Cloud Storage safe Metadata in Firestore what ID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, md5

I want to safe the metadata of every file I upload to Cloud Storage to a Firestore document, because it is easier to use. I need an attribute of the file to be the ID of the document. I can't really use the name because there may be a `/` inside it; I can't use the `id` attribute because it is a timestamp that also changes when I upload a new version of a file. Then there is the `md5Hash`, is it safe to use that as a ID or should I use something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any value as Firestore document as soon as it complies with the constraints detailed in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits):

- Must be valid UTF-8 characters
- Must be no longer than 1,500 bytes
- Cannot contain a forward slash (/)
- Cannot solely consist of a single period (.) or double periods (..)
- Cannot match the regular expression **.***

---

If your `md5Hash` value follows these constraints and is unique for each file, then it is perfect.

If not, you can use any library to generate this value (e.g. a UUID generator) and you could even use the Firestore SDK to do so, as follows with a dummy collection name:

```
const docId = firebase.firestore().collection("_").doc().id;
```